# How to compile python 3 without sigaltstack enabled?

Tags: python, python-3.x, compilation, makefile, configure

[This project](https://github.com/quarnster/lime#install-required-components) states that `Python 3 must be compiled without sigaltstack enabled.`  So what do I need to do to compile Python 3 without sigaltstack enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `./configure` with options you want. Then, you will get **`pyconfig.h`** in addition to `Makefile`, `config.log`, ... .

Edit the `pyconfig.h`: Find a line that contain `HAVE_SIGALTSTACK`, delete or comment out the line.

```
#define HAVE_SIGALTSTACK 1
```

Then, `make`, ...

---

How to confirm: Check whether `faulthandler` module has `_stack_overflow` function. It should not have it.

```
>>> import faulthandler
>>> print(hasattr(faulthandler, '_stack_overflow'))
False
```

---

According to [`faulthandler` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/faulthandler.html):

> The fault handler is compatible with system fault handlers like Apport
>   or the Windows fault handler. The module uses **an alternative stack** for
>   signal handlers if the sigaltstack() function is available. This
>   allows it to dump the traceback even on a stack overflow.